How to tell if one player is significantly better at a multi-player game?
I've build a poker simulation and have let 6 bots play a lot of games against each other (randomly seated, always the same six), how would you determine whether one player is significantly better than the rest?
https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aay2400 uses a T-test, but I'm a bit confused by two things:

The need for independence... aren't the players highly dependent on the performance of the other players? So I would need to do a paired T-test right (wasn't stated in the paper)?

Let's say I want to compare the top two players. Would it just be a matter of comparing each of the players in a paired T-Test? I made an example for how this might look in Python:


    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats
    
    ##### Seed for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(42)
    
    ##### Number of games
    n_games = 20
    
    ##### Create an empty DataFrame
    data = {
        'game': range(1, n_games + 1),
        'good': [0] * n_games,
        'bad': [0] * n_games,
        'random_1': [0] * n_games,
        'random_2': [0] * n_games,
        'random_3': [0] * n_games,
        'random_4': [0] * n_games,
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    ##### Randomly choose one winner per game
    winners = np.random.choice(['good', 'bad', 'random_1', 'random_2', 'random_3', 'random_4'], size=n_games)
    
    ##### Assign the winner for each game
    for i in range(n_games):
        df.loc[i, winners[i]] = 1
    
    ##### Perform the paired t-test between "good" and "bad"
    t_stat, p_value = stats.ttest_rel(df['good'], df['bad'])
    
    ##### Display the DataFrame and test results
    print(df)
    print(f"t-statistic: {t_stat}, p-value: {p_value}")
```


This question might be better for statistics.stackexchange.  But in any case, you might want to look into Analysis of Variance.
